# Completing a table of numbers

Tags: mathematics

(This is a question from a basic IQ preparation test)

What can be the next column if we consider the following table of numbers?

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 86 | 65 | 44 | X |
| 93 | 64 | 35 | Y |

1. X=23, Y=06
2. X=26, Y=03
3. X=03, Y=26
4. X=06, Y=23

Answer (score 4):

The answer is

> Option 1 because top goes down by 21, bottom by 29 each progressive number